# How do I fix this IF statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net, going behind another programmer. I need to base the action off of the membership type. So, I figured out how to do it! However, I have a unreacable code. Shouldn't I simply be able to to do an else statement to fix this issue? Visual Studio is saying unreacable code after my initial if statement.

```
string membership = gUserProfile.m_MembershipType;
        if (membership == "Free") ;

           return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");




        if (!GlobalFunction.IsAuthenticated)

            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");


        gUserProfile = new ProfileUser(gUserProfile.m_UserID);
        if(Session["newcomputer"] != null){
            ViewBag.newComputer = "1";
        }
        ViewBag.activeMenu = pPage;
        ViewBag.Content_Workstation = getAjaxWorkstation();
        ViewBag.Content_Server = getAjaxServer();
        return View(pPage,gUserProfile);
```

Comment: Well we don't know anything about `gUserProfile` so this question is unaswerable.  Make sure you post all relevant code.

Comment: please always use brackets, this is so unreadable, white-spaces that do nothing, random brackets at one if. If you be like no brackets, at least be consistent, do good indenting and use white-spaces to format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is an errant semicolon on line 2.

`if (membership == "Free") ; // whats that semicolon for?`

The if statement is controlling execution of the semicolon (no-op), not the return statement on the following line.

This means that your `return RedirectToAction` line will always execute. So, everything after it is unreachable.

Lesson: always use curly braces on your control flow:

```
if(membership == "Free") {
 return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
}
```

Additionally, if you allow VS to format your code, this becomes more clear. Use "ctrl-k+d" to format the document. This would dedent the `return RedirectToAction` line, making it clear that it wasn't under the `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much, VS was yelling about the braces, and I tried to use them, apparently in the wrong way. This fixed everything. Thanks for not going crazy about such a noob question :)

Comment: @CarterReidBurbage Everyone struggles with semicolons when they're new. Keep at it, they'll feel natural eventually.